# How to set max file size in Linux CeNTOS to server.log

Tags: linux, file, logging, size, centos

CeNTOS Linux

What to do:
Set max file size to 500 MB to file "server.log" (example)

How to do this?
Google no working solution found.

Comment: where is this "server.log" located?  Are you referring to the one in `/root/server.log`?

Comment: Can't find the server.log file anymore after 7 years :)
Answer below of logrotate was the best fit answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) to deal with log files.

It allows automatic rotation, compression, removal, and mailing of log files.  Each log file may be handled daily, weekly, monthly, or when it grows too large.

It has a size option, so you can configure it to stay under 500MB for your "server.log"